# Why "void" not works for optional parameter, when i use generic type?

Tags: typescript

When i use a "void" type directly as function's parameter, it works good, but when i use generic, it not inferred.

I use TypeScript 3.4.4.

```js
// It works perfectly :-)
function test(param: void){

}
test();
```

```js
// It doesn't works :-(
type T = {
    a: {
        value: string;
    };
    b: {
        value: void;
    };
};
function test<KEY extends keyof T>(key: KEY, param: T[KEY]["value"]) {}
test("b"); // ERROR: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. An argument for 'param' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a design limitation in the way the checks are implemented.
>
> Checking for void parameters that can be elided is done prior to generic instantiation, which means that instantiations that produce void parameters are ignored, as is the case in fails.
>
> This choice was made to avoid having to check every generic signature twice, and there were some issues with this breaking existing overload selections.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131#issuecomment-449634318

Comment: Thank you for answer! What do you think, is it a final desicion?

Comment: Yes. I don't think this will change anytime soon. The only thing you can do is to explicitly add `| void` to the second parameter, but it's not really convenient.